# Почему Yii2 не находит контроллеры?

Tags: php, yii2, framework

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу локально запустить сайт. Фреймвор Yii2.
настройки Nginx

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        charset UTF-8;
        access_log  /logs/localhost/nginx_access_log;
        error_log  /logs/localhost/nginx_error_log;

        root /www/localhost/http;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* .(jpeg|jpg|gif|png|css|js|pdf|txt|tar|rar|zip|exe|mkv|iso|avi|mp4)$ {
                expires 1y;
                if_modified_since before;
                root /www/localhost/http;
                access_log off;
        }
        location @deny {
                deny all;
        }
}
~
```

структура проекта

-framework

-http

-site

```
  'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules'=>array(
                // Главная
                '' => 'site/index',

                'test' => 'site/test',

                // Логин
                '<_c:(login|register|logout|lost)>' => 'user/<_c>',

                // Поиск
                'search/<page:\d+>' => 'site/search',
                'search' => 'site/search',

                // Сертификат
                '/certificate.html' => 'site/certificate',

                // Конкурс
                'contest' => 'contest/index',
                'contest/request' => 'contest/request',

                // Новости
                'news' => 'site/news',
                'news/page/<page:\d+>' => 'site/news',

                // В помощь
                'help' => 'help/index',
                'help/page/<page:\d+>' => 'help/index',
                'help/<id:\d+>-<post_url>.html' => 'help/post',

                // ФГОС
                'fgos' => 'fgos/index',
                'fgos/<parent:[a-z0-9-_]+>/<child:[a-z0-9-_]+>/' => 'fgos/category',
                'fgos/<parent:[a-z0-9-_]+>/<child:[a-z0-9-_]+>/page/<page:\d+>' => 'fgos/category',

                // Страница
                '<page_url:[a-z0-9-_]+>.html' => 'site/page',

                // Пост
                '<id:\d+>' => 'publications/post',
                '<id:\d+>/download/' => 'publications/download',
                '<id:\d+>/certificate/' => 'publications/certificate',
                '<post_id:\d+>/diplom/<author_id:\d+>' => 'publications/diplom',
                'download/<id:\d+>' => 'site/download',
                'rate/<post_id:\d+>/<direction:(plus|minus)>' => 'site/rate',

                // Пользователь
                'user/<username>' => 'user/info',
                'favorites' => 'user/favorites',
                'favorites/page/<page:\d+>' => 'user/favorites',

                // Добавит материал
                'add' => 'publications/add',
                'add/file' => 'publications/addfile',
                'add/preview' => 'publications/addpreview',

                // Админка
                'admin' => 'admin/index',

                // Категория
                'publications' => 'publications/index',
                'tags'         => 'publications/tags',
                '<category_url:[a-z0-9-_]+>/page/<page:\d+>' => 'publications/category',
                '<category_url:[a-z0-9-_]+>' => 'publications/category',
            ),
        ),
```

когда я захожу по адресу localhost 
отображается главная страница.
Но когда я хочу перейти по другим ссылкам, у меня появляется ошибка 404 Not Found

Почему фреймворк не видит контроллеры обработчики запросов ? Внешне всё вроде бы правильно и должно работать.

Comment: root /www/localhost/http; - уверены, что верный корень указан?
root должен быть в папке web

Comment: да. все сайты находятся по адвресу /www/**

Comment: где у вас лежит папка "web" ?

Comment: в папке framework. принтскрин прикрепил.

Answer (score 0):

Измените:

```
  root /www/localhost/http;
```

на

```
root /www/localhost/framework/web;
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Но index.php лежит в папке http, а в папке web только контроллеры. Но я сейчас подумал, там контроллеры названны по другому. Где такие названия испоьзуются ? В конфиге что то должно загружать  эти контроллеры.